# tomcat how to serve Http for locale requests, https for remote requests

Tags: java, http, tomcat, https

I have a Spring application inside a tomcat 8 container, this application has both local (intranet) and remote (internet) service. I would like to serve local services with simple HTTP and remote with HTTPS, is it possibile editing tomcat configuration and without filter requests inside the application?

I should distinguish local from remote requests by its ip address.

Comment: there is no proxy or anything between tomcat and the internet? So tomcat would have to deny connections on port 80 as soon as the request comes from an external ip?

Comment: Yes I would like to configure tomcat to listen local subnets with http and all others with https

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to. Your local network should be protected by a firewall, and you simply configure the firewall to only allow the secure port through.

Local traffic from the intranet doesn't go through the firewall, so it can access the HTTP port (80, 8080, ...).

External traffic comes in through the firewall, and it will block the HTTP port and allow the HTTPS port (443, 8443, ...).

Often with HTTPS, you don't even let Tomcat handle that, but instead put IIS (Windows) or Apache (Linux) in front of it. In that case you only have an AJP connector on localhost, and nobody can talk directly to Tomcat. The frontend web server will then do the required filtering and SSL/TLS handshake.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. For the first part (firewall), you're abolutely right, however in my case I'm not the sysadmin and I have to be sure that my application is safe also if the customer's sysadmin did not configure correctly its firewall. For the second part (ajp) are there advantages to use ajp considering that my tomcat doesn't contain static resource (img, css) but only web-services then I should redirect all requests from apache https to tomcat?

Comment: @Tobia One advantage is the shared port, i.e. the web server is already using ports 80 and 443 for serving other stuff, and you want to add a Tomcat webapp `http://server/myapp/...`. You can then tell the Apache server to forward `/myapp` to Tomcat, while it continues to serve the other stuff. Otherwise you'd have to use a different (non-standard) port for Tomcat. Even if you don't have other stuff yet, you may want that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have anything that's worth using https for, I'd opt to go https all the way: Otherwise you'll sooner or later have information leaks because you've missed some crucial part of configuration. HTTPS is no black magic anymore, performance impact is low if exists it at all.

In fact, the typical usecase that I see described is exactly opposite to yours: Intranet usage is typically more protected than internet access (which is thought to be anonymous, but it depends on the nature of the site). However, an Intranet is typically authenticated (more so than the internet side, typically) and I'd expect it to be quite important to protect the authentication. The only mixed-mode solution (http/https) that I could come up with for *this* situation is: Use HSTS [as soon as a user logs in](https://www.olafkock.de/ok/2014/12/30/http_and_https_mixed_mode_configuration.html), don't bother otherwise.

You're asking for the opposite of what I typically see - but my actually preferred solution (in all cases) is: Force https everywhere, use HSTS. And don't worry any more. Easier to maintain, Easier to setup and hard to get wrong.

Comment: Thank you Olaf, the local access of this application has also a browseable web page, therefore I don't want to give a selfsigned warning to clients. This (and https overhead if it exists) are the main reasons to not use only https

Comment: But you want to give selfsigned warnings to internet access? I don't get it. Certificates these days can be cheap or free (that's no reason any more to not go https). Overhead is virtually nonexistent. And you shouldn't train your intranet users to enter their credentialy on non-encrypted connections. I see no reason to go http-only for intranet access.

Comment: This will be a local POS application with a web interface and some remote rest webservices, I cannot will be mad to renew certificates every year to all my customers or in the worst case to block the application because I forget the renewal. I can understand your point of core in case of a company intranet services, but this Lan will be made of 1,2 max 3 POS workstation